# Chromium ProcessSingleton

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu-16.04

I just got a question recently about how to run chrome or chromium on our school machine (Ubuntu 16.04).

The machine is configured to mount user home folder via samba server with 700 permission. (I think it causes the problem of executing chrome)

When I execute the chromium-browser from terminal

`chromium-browser 
[26686:26686:1023/143803.603878:ERROR:process_singleton_posix.cc(278)] Failed to create /home/NETID/kharam/.config/chromium/SingletonLock: Operation not supported (95)
[26686:26686:1023/143803.603961:ERROR:chrome_browser_main.cc(1639)] Failed to create a ProcessSingleton for your profile directory. This means that running multiple instances would start multiple browser processes rather than opening a new window in the existing process. Aborting now to avoid profile corruption.`

I've tried to run chromium on the local account, and it ran.

Is there possible solution??????????

Thank you

Comment: I noticed that the school configured to mount NFS on home folder